# Installing FBAudienceNetwork (5.10.1) failed

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to update cocoapod but it failed every time. Did anyone face this problem, please help!

Error shows [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a79z.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1384)

with same

```
 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
```

how they explain it:

> Thanks for reporting. We are observing some issues with CDN where FAN
> binary is hosted and passed this on to relevant team to have a look
> and resolve.

And user, who was facing problem – was successful to install it after several attempts, finally.

Read, try, update me what's going on.

Comment: pod 'FBAudienceNetwork','~> 4.9.0' install successfully but latest version not

Comment: it still doesn't cancel the whole answer, it could be problem with CDN on their side, again.

Comment: Is there any download link so that I can can download and integrate manually in my project?

Comment: yes, please:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/adding-sdk/ios

Answer (score 1):

Changing the internet provider fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Not Working For me !